# Linux read file with control characters

Tags: linux, shell

I need to parse a file (which contains meaningful control characters) in a shell script line by line, but the "read" command will only take in text up until the '^@' character, cutting off the line too early. Is there a way to read a full line while keeping these control characters?

Comment: Don't try to use the shell to process binary data.

Comment: It uses C strings internally. The null byte is the string terminator.